# Regex for converting string to tuple

Tags: regex, string, scala

I have a string and need to convert it into a Tuple2 in scala. The string is:

`("abc",1),("def",9),("ghi",7)...`

The approach I am trying to take is to split the string in `("abc",1)`, `("def",9)` and `("ghi",7)` using **regex** and then create the respective Tuple. But I am unable to think of a regex that will split the string. I have tried `[)][,][(]` but it doesnot reveal the correct results.

OR may be there is a better way to create a tuple from a string without a regex?

Comment: How about ),( ?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397397/how-to-convert-formatted-string-to-tuple-in-scala

Comment: @MauricePerry that would not work as it will yield `("abc",1` `"def",9` and `"ghi",7)`

Comment: @samach321 remove heading ('s and trailing )'s

Comment: See https://ideone.com/Nbu2SO. Does it help?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes that works. can you please post it as an answer and explain what the regex is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your strings are always in the format you showed, you may strip the first and last parentheses by using a simpel `substring`, and then split with `)` followed with `,` that is followed with `(`.

See the [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/Nbu2SO):

```
val s = """("abc",1),("def",9),("ghi",7)"""
val res = s.substring(1, s.length-1).split("""\)\s*,\s*\(""")
res.foreach { l => println(l) }
```

Prints:

```
"abc",1
"def",9
"ghi",7
```

**Pattern details**:

- `\)` -  a literal `)`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `,` - a comma
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a literal `(`.

Since the triple-quoted string literal is used to define the regex, single backslashes denote literal backslashes, and do not need doubling.

Answer (score 0):

If it is C# you could do something like this:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\(""(?<string>[^""]*)"",(?<number>\d+)\)");
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
     yield return new Tuple<string, int>(match.Groups["string"].Value, int.Parse(match.Groups["number"].Value));
}
```

I beleive that this will do the job